# Automatically update SQL database when checkbox clicked

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm using PHP to list out a table from a SQL database, and each of those rows will have checkboxes in them for the user to keep track of whether or not part of that row is complete or not. I'd like it to be so that when a checkbox is checked or unchecked, the SQL database will automatically update. Is this possible, or will I need a "save data" button at the end of each row?

EDIT: Just to clarify, **I'm using php**. If I set the onclick action of the checkbox to `php/updatecheckbox.php?id=...`, how would I know the value of the checkbox? Also, wouldn't this force the page to refresh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

$fet['id'] is the id fetched from db for intimate which to modify.

```
    <a href=#><input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction('.$fet['id'].');">      </a>
 <script>
  function myFunction(del)
  {   

  var  rmvfile=del;

   if (confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete the file?") == true) {
    if(del!='')
   {
    $.ajax({
   type:'post',
      url:'query4.php',
          data:{rmvfile: rmvfile},
      success:function(msg){
 }
 });
  }
} 
}
</script>
```

Create a page query4.php

```
  <?php
  include "config.php";
  $s=$_POST['rmvfile'];
  $sel="update register set log=1 where id='".$_POST['rmvfile']."'";  //your query
 $sel1=mysql_query($sel);
 ?>
```

Comment: Would this refresh the page when the checkbox is clicked? I'm trying to make it so that when you click, it updates the database to either true or false, depending on the value of the checkbox. how would you pass the value to the script?